# Sprite-kit game lifecycle, properties and global variable?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my sprite-Kit game, my game goes through the various scenes, across which I want certain variables to be available. See the following diagram:

[image]

So the title screen loads the main game screen. When the 'wave' is finished (all objective complete or all lives lost), the end scene is presented with some stats. Then if the player has lives left the main game is loaded again, if not the title screen is presented again.

I want the player's score and number of lives left to be available across the main game scene and the end scene; the high score should be kept across all scenes.

I'm using global variables for these, whereas most of my variables are properties defined under the class.

The first time I had to do this (for my score property before I added a high score or multiple lives) I used a score property on every scene and passed it between scenes when I did the presentScene for the next scene, but that seemed clumsy, especially when I had to add more variables.

Is there a best practice for this i.e. should global variables be used/not be used and if not, is there a correct way to handle properties, perhaps controlled by where you initialise them e.g. in `init` compared to `didMoveToView`, which determines if they are re-initiialised when the scene is shown again?

EDIT:

Am I doing something 'wrong' when I go from the End Wave Scene back into the Main Game Screen that is causing the main screen to be re-initialised again? Is there a way to preserve it (with all it's properties) so it isn't fully re-initialied but it's didMoveToView is called again?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: I use a Class in sharedIstance, because use NSCoding and iCloud saves

Comment: Still trying to work through these answers & comments to work out what I'm doing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General rule of thumb: If you can avoid global variables, do so.

Now every node has a mutable dictionary called `userData`.  This is designed to be used to save data to a node.

Upon creation of your new scene, transfer whatever data you need from the old scene.

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed:....)
scene.userData["highscore"] = self.highscore
view.presentScene(scene)
```

Now in the new scenes `didMove(view:)` method, you read from said `userData`

As 0x141E has pointed out, remember you need to initialize `userData`, since chances are you have a custom class, you could do this in your init methods,  just remember to override all designated inits so that you have access to the convenience methods.

Also, as mentioned in the comments between Whirlwind and myself,  `SKNode` is `NSCoding` compliant,  so when you go and save your information, you can save the `SKNode` as a whole and `userData` will go along with it.

This means all you would have to do is write an extension for `SKNode` to save/load the node, and this avoids having to worry about managing another class.

Comment: I wonder how much people actually use / know about this property ... You got my upvote though because this property certainly may be used per node for non-sensitive data. Iirc using this property is the same as saving data on disk into plist file, right?

Comment: @Whirlwind it is just a regular NSMutableDictionary,  but what is nice is SKNode is NSCoding compliant, so when you save your SKNode to disk, the userData goes along with it, which is really nice.

Comment: Ah okay, I knew it can be saved to disk, but forgot that saving is not automatic :)

Comment: This works a lot better than a shared instance, which is something I would not recommend.  With this method, you could save your stats across individual SKNodes,  Like in a game I am working on, I have several characters that have  individual score stats,  a lot easier to just save the node associated with the character than having to manage an outside data source

Comment: Sometimes I think you're the most curt and abrupt commentator on game engines. Other times I think you dig up gems and should be an ambassador. This is one of those other times, mostly. Could you continue the first sentence (claim) with a phrase beginning with 'because' followed by a solid reason that then ends in a supportive link?

Comment: You need to create the `userData` dictionary before you can use it. Also, how do you access this data in an `SKNode` subclass before it's added to the scene or in a non-SpriteKit class or function?

Comment: @confused what are you referring to?  I will expand on it

Comment: @141e you build methods and delegates to communicate between these objects,  what would you need to be doing in SKNode that needs SKScene data before being added?  Chances are you need to evaluate your code and determine if there is a better way

Comment: @Knight0fDragon "General rule of thumb: If you can avoid global variables, do so." and all other claims you make. I'm not doubting your claims, not even vaguely. I think you've got a mountain of wisdom to share.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm in awe of your knowledge. But I wish it came with reasoning and links so I can bed that knowledge into my brain through understanding. I suck at rote learning.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if you get a spare couple of hours per day, you should seriously consider co-authoring a book on what you know, with someone keen on fleshing out your knowledge with diagrams and poignant verbosity. It would be of great help to anyone thinking about making games with Sprite Kit and Swift. HUGE HELP!

Comment: unfortunately this is not a tutorial site, this is a Q and A site,  so when it comes to basics, I try and refrain from teaching, I have been programming for over 20 years lol so it is hard for me to site sources when a lot of it came from books (I am 33 btw)  Here is a good reference to start when it comes to globals. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing_2009/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Fundamentals_of_Programming/Global_and_Local_Variables

Comment: @Confused I do not have the time for that, and there are a lot of times when I can be wrong,  which is why I love SO,  people can correct me, and we get the best possible answers.

Comment: SO certainly works for you, @Knight0fDragon, in that case. But don't sell yourself short. A good editor and a co-author and you'd embarrass the rest of the field writing about Sprite Kit. What I mean by a reason is, in this instance: "... because globals encourage bad habits" or "...because singletons have a performance hit" or "...because SpriteKit and Swift favour composition through GameplayKit and Prototoypes" or whatever is a good, punchy, one line reason for avoiding global variables, then the link.

Comment: In this way you're punching the point home, spreading wisdom and building up a library of references, to things that were uniquely pertinent but have general appeal, for a later effort at making a book or more formal layout of what you know.

Comment: well, when you see me saying things and want reference, never be afraid to comment lol  I usually check a couple of sites that has an answer close to mine before I post it.  Most of the time I am on SO when I need a break from work, so my answers will never be as well detailed as a lot of answers out there,  People like @Whirlwind usually do a great job with writing answers.

Comment: With the way Swift and Sprite Kit is constantly evolving,  I would not have the patience for it.  It is tough as it is now getting any info because sites do not stay up to date, and never say if it is used with Swift 1, 1.2,2,2.2,3 etc.  Then good luck with having to explain all of Apple bugs and workarounds (BTW, never report bugs to apple,  if you think I am curt and abrupt, they are far worse, on top of ignorant to their mistakes)  If stack exchange opened up a tutorial exchange,  that would be awesome, because  then we can get the info we need, and the community could keep it up to date.

Comment: @0x141E I updated my code to include your comment about initializing it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - passing the property from one scene to another and back again was what I was doing, but then when I added the high score, and the 'extraLifeAt' score etc, it got cumbersome. So you recommend doing exactly that but put them in .userData so it's only 1 property to pass around?

Comment: correct,  it is one NSDictionary you pass around, and it helps you with keeping your variables contained.  If you are going to move the reference, I recommend nilling out userData from the old scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I can see the logic in passing properties from one scene to another via userData or some other property (which I what I'm cyrrenyl going score, lives and highScore), it just feels 'clunky; to do so just so that I can then pass them back the next time I display that scene. I was wondering if I was doing something 'wrong' in causing my GameScene to be re-initiialised every time  (and score & lives set tot heir initial values each time) and that I could simply flip between the GameScene and the GameOverScene without completely initialising each one each time?

Comment: @SteveIves, if you override your `presentScene` method, you could do the transfers automatically and never have to worry about it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks, but I'd still be propagating my userData property  across scenes? i.e. store these 'persistent' variables in GameScene.userData and before moving to the endGameScene I do endGameScene.userData = self.userData and similarly when passing control from endGameScene to gameScene?

Comment: @SteveIves, you do it from the get go,  `void score : Int { get { return self.userData["score"]} set { self.userData["score"] = newValue}}`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - nice. I keep forgetting to use getters/setters and then kick myself later :-)

Comment: Perhaps I should consider adding an init(withScore: withLives:) to my GameScene?

Answer (score 8):

I know that many people work with generalized rules like "Don't use globals" or "Singletons are evil". These words of wisdom may be applicable at times, however another way of looking at them would be as tools to make you more efficient in getting your game finished.

There are times when globals/singletons are useful. Games and embedded systems play by different rules than conventional applications. These are typically resource constrained "applications" coupled with performance requirements. Globals are more common than you think in each. Singletons are also commonly in use. I've worked on both embedded systems and games and can say that on every project I've worked on, they've employed either globals, singletons, or both.

In practice, I use singletons over globals. Mainly because I don't have to worry about where to shove the global and what header file it belongs in. Note, the basis as to the why will differ from all you Swifties. For me this stuff is done in primarly in C++ with some Obj-C and a smattering here and there of Swift.

The need to manage game lifecycle is independent of `SpriteKit`. Many of the `SpriteKit` posts I see on SO have the devs embedding game state into the scene or VC. They are usually faced with some dilemma on how to move state to the next scene. While this approach may be good for what I will call "local state" (ie. state for the current screen, stage, etc), it is not good for global game state. For example, if you transition from a main screen to an option screen then back to main and then in the game, how are you tracking the changes to those options (eg. changing game difficulty)? Yes you certainly can pass around dictionaries, structs, or what have you around. But at some point of time, you are going to discover that having one common and convenient dumping ground for it all is more convenient. This "dumping ground" would be globals/singletons.

Now before ya'll start yelling at me, there is a catch to all this crazy talk of globals and singletons. I'm not saying create alot of globals/singletons. Rather, be controlled aboutwhen/if you employ globals/singletons.

I'm not talking a gazillion if 'em. I'm talking like one (although I usually have a handful in use). Enter our ficticious friend, the `GameManager`.

Let's walk down a very simple scenario of a space shooter. Say I have multiple screens such as the title screen, main screen, the in game screen, and the end wave screen. There are certain bits of information that are useful to be passed to the different screens. For example high score or even current score. Those may be values that you want to display on various screens/scenes. So where do you store the score? How do I pass the score between them? For example, if the last high score is displayed on all screens, where do I keep that value?

```
class GameManager : NSObject {
    // Overall game state, GameState is probably some enum
    var state:GameState
    var lastState:GameState

    // Sometimes tracking scenes is useful
    var currentScene:SKScene?
    var nextScene:SKScene? // Sometimes helpful if you need to construct the next scene and it takes a non-trivial amount of time

    // These are the globals we need to share to different "parts" of the game
    var score: UInt
    var highscore: UInt
    var lives: Uint
    var stage: Uint

    var highscores:[Uint]   // A list of all the high score for the user. You would probably want HS based on other users too

    // Egads a singleton!
    static let sharedInstance = GameManager()
}
```

If this was a global, it would have some global definition of the instance outside any scope. Like:

`var theGameManager : GameManager`

So if you want to udpate the score, you'd do

`theGameManager.score += 100`

If it was a singleton updating the score would look something like:

`GameManager.sharedInstance.score += 100`

Okay the singleton syntax is a little longer, but perhaps a little less cryptic than the global as to where/what this is.

But now here is where you can have a little more power in things. Let's say when you add a score, every multiple of 100000 scores you an extra life. I can now easily leverage the setter and use that setter to also reward the extra life.

For example this:

`GameManager.sharedInstance.score += 100 // the magic of the 100000 for extra life happens automagically in the setter`

versus something potentially like this:

```
myScore += 100

// Do logic to find out if we get an extra life. 
// Is this done in a method and if so where does this method live?
// Or is it straight up code which will be duplicated?
```

Code like this which helps manage global game state is all neatly contained within the `GameManager`. *In other words, the `GameManager` doesn't just maintain values, but it also provides a way of encapsulating functionality around those values.*

Hmm, it seems the `currentScene` is also here? Why would that be? The `GameManager` would also be an excellent way to manage the changing of the scenes. More likely done through the game state. Maybe something like:

`GameManager.sharedInstance.gameState = GameOverState`

Behind the scenes, the `gameState` setter can then do the magic of swapping out scenes.

These are but a few examples of the practical nature of this approach.

Regarding the talk of loading/storing, this is can also be done through the `GameManager` if desired. Although for myself, I typically treat it independently based on some data within the `GameManager`. And this brings up another distinction. I would typically encapsulate ideas within the `GameManager`. For example, I would probably have a `Player` and that would make `GameManager` look like this:

```
class GameManager : NSObject {
    // Overall game state, GameState is probably some enum
    var state:GameState
    var lastState:GameState

    // Sometimes tracking scenes is useful
    var currentScene:SKScene?
    var nextScene:SKScene? // Sometimes helpful if you need to construct the next scene and it takes a non-trivial amount of time

    // These are the globals we need to share to different "parts" of the game
    // Note player state is done through this object. This way I can pass around only player when needed.
    var player: Player

    var stage: Uint

    var highscores:[Uint]   // A list of all the high score for the user. You would probably want HS based on other users too

    // Egads a singleton!
    static let sharedInstance = GameManager()
}
```

Wait you say; "But I don't like this global/singleton jazz. Why don't I just pass this object through to everyone that needs it." The answer is "you can". But in practice, you'll start to find this becomes tedious. You also may find that you discover you need the `GameManager`, but the caller never had the `GameManager` passed to it. This means now you're reworking a few methods to pass this object through.

Soooo are globals/singletons evil? You can be your own judge for it. Everyone will have there solution of choice. And if it works for you, use it. For me, it's a no brainer. The benefits of using it for ***consistent ease of use in accessing/managing global game state across your implementation*** make it an obvious choice.

> So I'm adding a little more info here for an already long answer to
>   try clarify a few things.

My choice of singleton or global would be on usage, platform, and language. It is also dependent upon the game code base as well. It is not meant to be a dumping ground of just any data. If utilized, the contents should be carefully considered and when possible, use other containers for the contents (ie. wrap them in classes). So while my first example had player information dangling out (done to more easily convey the idea), in reality I would have `PlayerState` contain player data. Note this may not be the player in it's entirety, but perhaps some shared info that needs to live beyond the in-game life of the player.

```
class PlayerState {
    var score:Uint
    var highscore:Uint
    var lives:Uint
}

// Simplified GameManager
class GameManager {
    var state:GameState
    var lastState:GameState

    var player:PlayerState

    // Egads a singleton!
    static let sharedInstance = GameManager()
}
```

Additionally, I would end up passing around the `PlayerState` instance versus expecting code to always grab it through the global/singleton.

So for example I would do this:

```
func doSomething(playerState:PlayerState) {
    var score = playerState.score   

    // Blah blah blah
}
```

verus

```
func doSomething() {
    // Whee I have singleton
    var score = GameManager.player.score

    // Blah blah blah
}
```

Effectively what I'm doing is using the singleton as *anchor points to access data objects* more easily and then if needed, pass it around. In other words, While they are being employed, I also do not want my code riddled with `GameManager.sharedInstance`.

As mentioned, there are certainly a bunch of cons to this approach. One of which is concurrency. However, I will point out that concurrency still can occur with data even if it is not in a global/singleton.

My point of this addition is that game dev (and coding in general) involves a degree of practicality. Not only are you doing a balancing act with the system resources to present your game, but presumably you're making the game for people to play it. And for that to happen you need to get it done. Everyone wants to make a perfect snowflake, but what is the timecost for that perfection? At the start of the answer I indicated this technique is a tool. Globals/singletons won't be for everyone. At the same time, one should also not just blindly follow design mantras. If it can be an effective tool for you and help you finish your game faster, then its worthwhile doing. There will always be another game to write and you can then decide based on experience what worked and what did not.

Comment: Mother of all answers. With WISDOM, too! Thank you!!! I'm printing this and pointing to it every time I dare question my desire to use singletons and globals. Now... if only I knew the difference...

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. It's always good to look at diff approaches as possible tools and try and set aside knee-jerk reactions based on what everyone says is appropriate. An item often lost is you need to get your project done and to do so everyone is faced with tradeoffs. Sometimes those tradeoffs will make people cringe. That's okay. For now, if I were you, I'd probably think of singleton first v. globals. Best thing is to build as much as you can, stay open minded, and learn from your mistakes and others!

Comment: @MobileBen, this is not 20 years ago, "getting the project done" is not the only thing you need to be thinking about when designing, which is why patterns and practices are in place.  Code is living and updating and you need to design so anyone can maintain it (You won't live forever), otherwise you waste more time with fixing and updating than you would have getting it done right the first time. That is why people cringe when they see tradeoffs like singletons and globals, because they realize how much time they will be wasting when dealing with them.

Comment: Dear @Knight0fDragon, he covered you in the fourth to last sentence, and the third to last. Aside from which, in this situation it makes a lot of sense. OOP isn't the root of all evil, but the love of it surely is ;)

Comment: @Confused I am not sure what you are referring to,  if you are referring to the 4th to last line in his answer, then no, he does not cover me.  Like I said code is living, so a game is never finished.  Look at all the successful games out there today, and how many have changed since its inception.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon **"Globals/singletons won't be for everyone. At the same time, one should also not just blindly follow design mantras."**

Comment: @Confused, Ok that is why I said what I said. the idea of design patterns is so that multiple people follow a similar standard, and others can pick up your project without having to waste time on the project, because you won't live forever.  Plus it allows you as a programmer to pick up the code a year later and not go WTF did I write lol

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Everytime I see "self.blahblah" or "super.thisthat" I want to destroy several computers. OOP is a rort, as far as I'm concerned, designed to keep people busy, forever, being busy.

Comment: @Confused lol I have a spritekit chat on here of you just want to shoot the breeze on things. Let's not flood the answer

Comment: @Confused I am on my phone now, but if you hit the group on the top left, where you can pick your exchange group, you will see chat next to SO,  just pick that, search sprite kit.  If it doesnt show up. Then click on something like archived chat or something to pull up the closed ones due to inactivity,  and then tag me whenever you are in it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so where exactly did I state that "getting the project done" is the sole consideration? And are you asserting that MS, when making Windows 95, only worried about getting things done and didn't worry about maintaining code? Development has a many variables one must consider. Deadlines happen to be one of them. I make the assumption that many people posting questions in the sprite kit are nascent indie game devs with the hopes of making a hit or perhaps aspirations of going pro. The stark reality is most games are going to fail. There will be no maintenance.

Comment: I've presented an approach. No where have I said you must. I've stated it's not for everyone. I think devs learning the ropes are better off learning how to work through the problems and learn how to weigh options. In other words "work the problem, don't let it work you". Additionally, getting done does matter. Unless you are doing it for pure hobby, I suppose. How else does one learn to determine best approach? By being willing to experiment and being open minded. You may find this interesting. http://www.mcshaffry.com/GameCode/index.php/Thread/1805-Dependency-Injection-in-a-game-engine/

Comment: @MobileBen I am well aware that there will not be maintenance, but you should not be designing to fail. We should not be teaching people to just get it done and that is ok,  I can understand if you were saying use work around in situations when you need to get it done as a last resort for a deadline after exhausting good programming practices, but the way you have explained it, you want to use it in the very beginning of the development cycle.

Comment: @Knight0fDragonYou have your opinions. I have mine, which is based on working on many game projects from the blockbuster with a team size in the hundreds to tiny projects. People should take in the info and come up with their own opinions. Despite what you think, you can successfully use globals/static classes/singletons in a project. If you have a chance, you should read that article. One of the guys in the thread, which you'll undoubtedly not like his viewpoint (spoiler alert), talks about what they did on the Sims.

Comment: This post is the gift that keeps on giving. I'm learning to base my needs around the idea that something permeates throughout the game world and be carefree about it, thanks to this post. I don't care if it's atypical OOP, it's working, and working WELL!

Answer (score 4):

During the execution of a game many things could happen, a game have a crash, the player close the app, internet stops, a node could be paused from a parent (so it will be skipped when a scene processes actions). For this reason I agree with Simone Pistecchia comments: you could prepare a "storage manager" class to load and save to file your player stats, use NSCoding to declare and initialize them, use a Shared Instance class to handle them across the project. With this way you could load and save your vars when you need and show them also out of the game (to your main menu for a "High Scores" scene for example  of wherever you want)

Comment: Ray Wenderlich explain this argument also here https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2

Comment: Is this not overkill just to keep track of the player's current score?

Comment: I prefer to save a single var to a file than an intere scene or node with all elements, this also improves the data load times by storage and do not save unnecessary data such as textures, choose your strategy based on your project.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, if you save the node, you can allow the to resume where the player last left off,  Kind of like a snapshot with an emulator,  of course, NSMutableDictionary is also NSCoding compliant, so you only have to save that in your save method,  then you do not need to worry about singletons which could lead to theading issues if not done correctly.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I dont like this kind of strategy for many reasons where some of them I have already explained: a node could be an entity composed by dynamic entities like node childrens and node subchildrens and you have to handle loading and saving states also for removed childrens.There could be problems also when you have to insert new properties and handle the new entry with loading/saving procedures(async): too many cases like that could generate new issues.

Comment: That is definitely not true,  your scenario will happen regardless of what goes on,  the only difference is you have to handle every scenario, and i handle only the added things, which should be done regardless to maintain being compliant with nscoding,  that is why apple forces you to require the init.  The only important difference between the two methods at the end of it all is you are global, and I am local.  Both have there merits,  but at the end of the day,  I try to focus on data encapsulation to be a high priority,  because I have no idea how evolved an app can get.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon this is an interesting discussion. I agree with Alessandro, let me explain. What happen if you make a game with 100 nodes and in your 2.0 app upgrade you make a decision to store all your data in iCloud or/and in Core Data or you want to introduce a personal encryption?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia ... not sure how that matters with the method of choice,  I already do both,  like I said,  it comes down to a global singleton vs local storing,  that it is,  and although MobileBen makes a good defense for singletons,  what he proposes should not be done by everyone, it should only be done during the optimization process of your app. It takes a lot of work to write a singleton to perform correctly,  more work that if you just kept your data contained to the instances that need the data.

Comment: @SteveIves, whether it is overkill is an interesting question. What most don't realize is a game needs to be built in a malleable fashion. Today it is just current score. But what about tomorrow? Things will change far more than one can imagine. Say you release a game, it's doing well, but people clamor for stored powerups? How will you now do that if you go with an "overly simplified" approach. You certainly will probably get it to work, but at what code expense? The more severe the changes, the higher the risk of unforeseen bugs.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, to clarify, what I discussed was not an optimization. Rather it is something that should be done from the onset. In the end, it provides better data encapsulation, code locality, and flexibility with the additional benefit of it being less tedious to code around. It does not take a lot of work to write a singleton correctly with Swift (or use it properly). Even for Obj-C for that matter. People have been screaming "Singleton's are evil" as a mantra. They are an effective tool which is overly demonized.

Comment: @Mobileben,  it is the exact opposite of data encapsulation,  you have data available in a global state,  you have zero code locality,  again global state,  you do have flexibility, but it is too flexible and dangerous unless done correctly, which is why I said it is more work than dealing with local transferring to begin with.  That is why it should be done during the optimization stage.  It becomes difficult to maintain when working on large projects or in teams,  due to anybody having free access to it, you can never guarantee you have complete control of your data

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I respectfully disagree. This is indeed encapsulation of particular types of data. I'm not saying to shove just anything there. In my answer, I actually cited I don't just use one item. There are other things I do, however to list them out would just provide more points of confusion. Code locality, yes. It has it too. Because the `GameManager` manages the data. As an FYI, I do this stuff for a living. Mobile, PC, console. I am not talking speculation. This stuff is used in the field to varying degrees. And it certainly isn't for everyone.

Comment: @mobileben  I do this too,  I am not saying they are useless,  best way I can put it is they are jack hammers,  in the experienced hands,  they make great tools,  but most people will end up doing more damage then it is worth

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I wouldn't consider this a jackhammer which needs skill to wield. This is one of the far easier concepts in games. People need to keep in mind that Apple's goal with SpriteKit is to lower the knowledge needed to make a game. They are not game devs. Demos provided by Apple are also not by game people. But people making games with this tech take the demos as "best practices", when in industry we would not do it that way. Presenting a more "advanced" approach is a way that people can learn to be more effective. Sure there may be bumps, but the gains are generally worth it.

Comment: @MobileBen,  the singleton approach is not Apples way,  even there own frameworks are using less and less singletons. I wouldn't even go as far as calling them advanced techniques,  they are short cuts and work arounds.  We some how lost site of the question. This question is about his life cycle and what is best practice,  not shortcuts. I have yet to find any kind of article saying singleton is best practice, more like common beginner practice lol

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, yep this has perhaps strayed. Note that I never said Apple does it this way. Read what I wrote. I said people often take the Apple demos as "best practices". I also clearly indicated the global/singleton is not an advanced concept. You were the one likening it to a jackhammer. 'Twas also the reason I double quoted the advanced to highlight the lack of advance-itude. Anyways, I'm done with this comment thread.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Singletons are one of the core design patterns used throughout Cocoa. Apple’s Developer Library considers the singleton one of the “Cocoa Core Competencies.” and there are many examples in Apple’s code samples. I would not exactly say that is not the way to work for Apple.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano that is why i said Apple is using it less and less,   In case you haven't noticed,  we are using less and less of cocoas with swift,  and pretty soon, we may not be using it at all, who knows.  I cannot remember the last time I needed to directly access a singleton from apples framework,  I would need to check on it, it may just be habit and I don't realize I am using it.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano  main operation queue actually makes sense to be a singleton, because that is something that is used absolutely by every instance of every class, directly or indirectly.  This is not something new though, and Apple  puts all the necessary work into guarding their singletons

Comment: Swift 3, Foundation, OperationQueue has a singleton called the main operation queue (WWDC 2016 - Tony Parker). They work to improve the way that you use the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch APIs in Swift in 2016, they praise Cocoa, not speak to use "less and less of cocoas with swift". I don't know what are your sources, Im talking about Session 207 , WWDC 2016.

Comment: Are we missing something here?  The root object behind foundation is NSObject, which Swift doesn't use as much anymore,  they still need to maintain their Objective C counterpart, I wouldn't exactly call that praising,  once all of foundation dependency is removed from Swift,  I can definitely see them replacing UIKit

Comment: You realize you're talking about adbandone Objective C, this opened other 
interesting arguments, but we must not leave the topic. Please give the sources about your statements. Thank you.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano  I am not sure what sources you need, just look at every iteration of swift, you can infer what I am discussing here.  Yes, I can definitely see Objective C being abandoned in the future once Swift is in a stable enough state.  As for the root class, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html